# Cross validation function from which programming language is more appropriate?

Tags: r, cross-validation, matlab, resampling

I'd like to use resample to achieve stable results of an unsupervised algorithm that finds clusters in data. I'll use k-fold cross validation repeated many times but I'm in doubt if I should use R or Matlab.
I've looked at the `caret` package from R but the train function requires a predictor and my algorithm isn't available as a method. Is there any similar function in R or Matlab that I can perform k-fold cv repeated about 100 times but without predictors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend the `mlr` package, its learning curve is steeper than `caret` but it offer many other functionalities and I find it actually easier to use and modify.

It offers off the shell some cluster analysis learners, [check the list of already implemented learners](http://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/release/html/integrated_learners/index.html#cluster-analysis-8). Adding your own isn't really that hard, check how to do it [in their tutorial](http://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/release/html/learner/index.html#constructing-a-learner) or also in their github repository (for example, [the KMeans implementation](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/blob/master/R/RLearner_cluster_SimpleKMeans.R)).